# If $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $A ⊴ C(A)$ where $C(A)$ is the centralizer of $A$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> If $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $A ⊴ C(A)$ where $C(A)$ is the centralizer of $A$.

I am a bit confused. Here's my argument.

Given that $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Thus, $gag^{-1} \in A $ for all $g \in G$ ------$1$

If $A$ is a normal subgroup of $C(A)$ then it must be the case $gag^{-1} \in A $ for all $g \in C(A)$

Pick $g \in C(A) $ then we have $gag^{-1} = a$ for all $a \in A$.
since $C(A)$ is a subset of $G$ by $1$ it should follow $gag^{-1} \in A $ for all $g \in C(A)$ as well.

What I am missing here? I am not confident about the proof

Comment: Is it $A \leq C(A)$ given in your case? This is false in general...

Comment: @Desperado You mean $A$ is a subgroup of $C(A) $?

Comment: @Desperado  $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ is the only given thing

Comment: @Tim can you explain a bit more

Comment: What you are missing in your proof, is to show that $A$ is a subgroup of $C(A)$.

Comment: @Desperado how can i prove it? any hint

Comment: It is not true in general that $A$ is a subgroup of $C(A)$, so what you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: @DerekHolt if its a subgroup then my argument is correct?

Comment: Take $G=S_3\times \mathbb Z_2$, then $A:=S_3$ is a normal subgroup, with $C(A)= \mathbb Z_2$, so it cannot be proven that $A\subseteq C(A)$

Comment: G is Abelian group?

Comment: @Tim nope, no mention about that

Comment: @Lucifer $C(A) =\{ g\in G : ga=ag \:\:\forall a \in A \}$, 
A is normal subgroup is not sufficient to prove $A\subset C(A)$. 
You should miss out something. A may be abelian or 
it is not a centralizer but an normalizer

Comment: @Tim if A is an abelian group, how can I proceed with the proof?

Comment: @Lucifer, if $A$ is abelian, then it is trivial that $A \leq C(A)$, and then your argument works.

Comment: @Lucifer "A is a normal subgroup of C(C(A))" or  "C(A) is a normal subgroup of G " are also possible questions